# Why wont this open a file on launch of google cloud

Tags: bash, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, rdp

```
sysprep-specialize-script-ps1
    
Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

I did the RDP and wait a couple of minutes to see, no file started. The path is also correct.

Below is a photo of the setup

[image: Why doesn't it start]